# How do I set variable to int and String?

Tags: java, validation, set

I am making a card class, and need to set the face (The number on the card) to the numbers 1-13. However, on a card, a 1 is an ace, a 13 is a king, a 12 is a Queen, and an 11 is a jack. How do I also set the number 1, and 11-13 to a string such as ace, king, queen, or jack? Any help is appreciated!

```
        public void setFace(int f)
        {       
          if(f >= 1 && f <= 13)
            face = f;
          else
            face = 1;
        }

        public int getFace()
        {
          return face;
        }
```

Comment: enum is best for what you need

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you have field like

```
public int face;
```

I guess it will work if it's what you meant

```
    public String getFace() {
    switch (this.face) {
    case 1:
        face = "Ace";
        break;
    case 11:
        face = "Jack";
        break;
    case 12:
        face = "Queen";
        break;
    case 13:
        face = "King";
        break;
    default:
        return Integer.toString(face);
        break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

What do you think about this code..?

```
public void setFace(int f) {

    switch (f) {
    case 1:
        face = 1;
        break;
    case 11:
        face = 1;
        break;

    case 12:
        face = 1;
        break;

    case 13:
        face = 1;
        break;

    default:
        face = f;
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: I think this is ugly and error prone :-) ... since you asked.

Comment: you can use enum in switch

Answer (score -1):

How about using enums?

```
public enum CardValue {
    ACE(1), TWO(2), THREE(3), ..... KING(13);

    private int value;

    private CardValue(int value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    public int getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    public CardValue getValueFor(int x) {
        // iterate through CardValue enum and return correct instance of the enum
    }
}
```

Comment: @jigitter:you didn't provide any constructor in you enum,is that ok?

Comment: I dunno about this...  if you have to call most of your enums TWO, THREE, FOUR, etc., that's to me an indication this is really an integer, and that an integer, instead of an `enum`, is the right abstraction.  But this is a difficult case because of the face cards, so I expect others will have different opinions.

Comment: The nice thing is that you don't have "magic numbers", you aren't dealing with dozens of constants, and you can wrap up comparators and other related logic neatly.  This is really just taking a page out of the Effective Java book.

Comment: @jgitter:But your enum name is CardValue, not Card.

Comment: @jgitter:my pleasure.